# How to deploy TensorFlow model to cloud?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, coreml

I want to deploy my deep learning model to the cloud so that I can upload photos on an iPhone App and the model handles the detection and returns the output.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can deploy a tensorflow model. Read through the following official documentation.

[TensorFlow - Serving Models](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving)